# inout param with empty object since nil won't work

Tags: swift

We can't pass nil to inout param, is there a short and concise way to create an empty object literal on the fly and pass to it for the sake of it,

let's say sometimes when we have nothing to pass, wanna pass an empty array, a empty dictionary or class literal object, how would that work in the following case?

```
func test(inout param: Any) {
    println(param)
}
```

//call

```
test(&[]())
```

Edit - inout with nil works

```
func test(inout param: Any?) {
    println(param)
}

var p: Any? = nil

test(&p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that won’t work here.

You need to give more than `[]` to declare an array. You need to give some indication of it’s element type.  Either in the brackets e.g. `[Int]()` or from other context i.e. if `test` took an `[Int]` arg not an `Any`.  Otherwise the compiler has no idea what type you mean by `[]`.

You cannot pass literals (for example, `nil`) into an `inout` parameter.  In fact you can’t pass any kind of immutable value, including temporary objects like `[Int]()`, or variables declared with `let`.  The only things you can pass to an `inout` parameter are “lvalues” – that is, things that can be on the left-hand side of an assignment.  That means even if you changed this to `test(&Int) it won’t work.

Finally, even if you declare `var a = [Int]()` and then try to call `test(&a)` you’ll get an error, because the implicit copy of `a` from an array to an `Any` will result in another immutable temporary, which also can’t be passed as an `inout`.

Comment: Thanks sir, here's some context, the problem I've is with structs and dictionaries that they are passed by value and not reference, and sometimes I don't have anything and I pass nil (optional params). Fine I then declare a function with inout param, but then I'm forced to always have something to pass to them. My requirement is basically to have structs and dicts to pass by reference as an optional param using `Any?` and seems impossible, this pushes me back to use `AnyObject?` instead

Comment: and then of course this requires me to create an internal class instead of a variable, add some vars in it, create an object and pass to the function (verbose)

Comment: If you’re passing arrays as `inout` because you think that’s more efficient, it’s not.  They are copy-on-write, passing them by value is much the same as passing a pointer.  Even with user-defined structs with multiple members, “passing by value” to a function does not mean they’re going to be copied. This isn’t C++. Trust the compiler and use the language rather than fighting it.

Comment: not thinking about efficiency, actually expecting them to change the passed dictionary or structs, and since it's passed by value, any changes they do or any other functions they pass for change, the caller isn't going to get those changes

Comment: I've done some edits to my question, seems i could pass nil to an inout param in case I don't have a value, and then if I've a value, I can create a struct or dictionary and pass to a function for changes

Comment: yes a var containing a value of nil will work – just not a literal or a temporary